# Await on item being present in a list

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently looking for a way to monitor a list for an item to be added (although it may already be in the list) with a certain ID. The below example demonstrates what I want to do, however I was hoping there would be a neater approach to this.

```
var list = new List<string>();
var task = new Task<bool>(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (list.Contains("Woft"))
            return true;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    return false;
});
```

I would appreciate any suggestions, and can elaborate if required.

EDIT: I'm not sure how I would use a `CollectionChanged` handler for this, still not sure I'm describing the problem well enough, here is a more complete example.

```
class Program
{
    private static List<string> receivedList = new List<string>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thing = new item() { val = 1234, text = "Test" };
        var message = new message() { id = "12", item = thing };
        //This would be a message send
        //in the receiver we would add the message id to the received list.
        var task2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            receivedList.Add(message.id);
        });
        task2.Start();
        var result = EnsureReceived(thing, message.id);
        if (result == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message not received!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.text + " " + result.val);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //This checks if the message has been received
    private static item EnsureReceived(item thing, string id)
    {
        var task = new Task<bool>(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (receivedList.Contains(id))
                    return true;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            return false;
        });
        task.Start();
        var result = task.Result;
        return result ? thing : null;
    }
}

class message
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public item item { get; set; }
}

class item
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int val { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could use an `ObservableCollection<>` instead of a List. That way you will only need to poll once.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to lock even while reading from the list.

Comment: Why are you checking the list 10 times for "Woft"?

Comment: @usr I hadn't forgotten, I was just giving the smallest example possible.

Comment: @Blam That was just a basic example, the real code would check if the list contains an element with the required id. (replace `list.Contains` with `list.Any(f=>f.id=="123")`).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you want to do is use an `ObservableCollection` and subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event. That way, you'll have an event fire whenever the collection is modified. At that point, you can check if the collection has the element you're expecting.

Even better, the `CollectionChanged` event handler will receive `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`, which contains a `NewItems` property.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this would help in my situation, I have elaborated on the problem above so that it is hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement own type, what intercept all operations to add items and exposes [`ReadOnlyList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). Then create an event `ItemAdded` with added item value (you will have to rise up multiple events when adding a collection obviously). Subscribe to it, check, do whatever.